# Connecting to Dynamics CRM with ClientSecret Fails

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm having a real issue connecting to CRM from a web service (or any .Net page in the project).
Connections stopped working using AuthType=Office365 so I changed the conn string to use ClientSecret.
The connection works OK in XRMToolBox but not in the webpages. I'm running out of ideas.
Are there better ways to capture the login issue errors than just returning "Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM". Im at a loss!

The site is .Net 4.7.2 and the connection test code is below;

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System;
using System.Net;

public partial class c3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        string crmConnectionString = "AuthType='ClientSecret';Url='https://xxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com';ClientId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';ClientSecret='xxxxxxxxxxxxx'";
        CrmServiceClient service = new CrmServiceClient(crmConnectionString);

        if (service.IsReady)
        {
            Response.Write("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(service.LastCrmError);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify one thing first. This is a written message and I am trying to write it as polite as possible, please don't judge what you may consider my attitude from what I am writing or if you like the answer or not.

Posting here or on Dynamics Community doesn't give you a different answer.
As you wrote here `The connection works OK in XRMToolBox` so we are 100% sure the Url, ClientId and ClientSecret are correct.
As I wrote you on Dynamics Community it may be something related to your system/installation, because I just tried with a new ASP.NET Web Application, .NET Framework 4.7.2, Forms (because the code you posted belongs to a Forms type) with a trial of mine and it works. Screenshot:

[image: ASP.NET Web Application]

I really don't like to post answers `it works on my machine` because they are usually not useful, but I tried to be as much as helpful as possible inside the Dynamics Community Forums, I also verified that your connection works on my machine, I now verified that the CrmServiceClient works inside an ASP.NET Web Application, so am I asking again, is it possible that is something in your machine that is not working properly? Also because XrmToolBox connection works as you wrote.
And consider that the line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` is useless but also if you add it (and I tested) the connection works.

I trust you when you say is not working for you, but this doesn't mean it doesn't work for everybody else.

Comment: I posted in multiple places for different opinions. In the end I rebuilt the entire project in VS2019 (was2015). After installing all the references one by one and using a client secret it now works. Thanks for the help

Comment: As a follow on point... all of the supported connection strings and formats are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving AppId and RedirectUri in the connection string as below:
"AuthType=OAuth;Username= xxx.onmicrosoft.com; Password=xxx;Url= https://xxx.crm4.dynamics.com; AppId=xxxx; client_secret = xxxx; RedirectUri=app://xxx;LoginPrompt=Never"

For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzPdkZ7N2Gw